# ruby Tk app running in while loop displays twice and then stops responding

Tags: ruby, loops, tk-toolkit

I'm pretty new to ruby and am trying to implement a Tk application that will display a window prompting for input at a certain interval.  In between the interval I want the window to not display in any taskbars, etc. and so I've implemented the following code that seems to work perfectly the first time through, but after the window displays the second time and I enter text in the TkEntry and click the TkButton the window is dismissed and never returns.  I've tried putting in some "puts" calls at key locations to see what is happening and it seems that it never even makes it past the call to "displayUi".

*EDIT:
I'm running ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32] on a Windows 7 system (in case that makes any difference)

Any help (even if it's providing a different mechanism to accomplish the same goal) would be appreciated, but please keep in mind that I'm a ruby noobie.  Thanks!

```
require "tk"

class Sample
    attr_accessor :root, :active
    @active = false

    def initialize
        # init
    end

    def entry (task)
        # do some work here

        @active = false
    end

    def displayUi ()
        @active = true

        if (@root.nil?)
            @root = TkRoot.new { title "Sample App" }
        else
            # already running just restart
            Tk.restart
        end

        TkLabel.new(@root) {
            text  'Sample Text'
            pack { padx 15; pady 15; side 'left' }
        }

        statusInput = TkEntry.new(@root) {
            pack('side'=>'left', 'padx'=>10, 'pady'=>10)
        }
        statusInput.focus

        response = TkVariable.new
        statusInput.textvariable = response

        TkButton.new(@root, :text => "Ok", :command => proc { entry(response.value); @root.destroy }) {
            pack('side'=>'left', 'padx'=>10, 'pady'=>10)
        }
        Tk.mainloop
    end
end

i=0
st = Sample.new
while (true)
    if (!st.active)
        st.displayUi()
    end
    sleep(1) 
end
```

Comment: The best way to do this is to withdraw the real root toplevel and make your own each time through. Like that, when the window goes away you can make another one without having to reinitialize Tk. (Not an answer though: don't know enough about how to write this in Ruby. I know Tk from another language…)

Comment: Agreed with Donal. Incidentally, I tried this script on Linux ruby and Windows and it does what you'd hoped for on Linux but not on Windows. Regardless, restarting Tk shouldn't be necessary